# Laravel 8 - Collecting URL param on index causes any URL's entered to collect as well

Tags: laravel, routes, parameter-passing, url-parameters, laravel-8

I'm collecting a parameter on root and passing to the controller. e.g., https://www.test.com/?label=value

`Route::get('/{label?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\LabelController@index')->name('home');`

The issue is that everything entered is captured, which a problem.

E.g., *https://www.test.com/asdkfj* passes *asdkfj* instead of returning 404 as expected.

Comment: that is how parameters work, they capture that segment

Comment: Whitelist params or if there are too many check in the db.

Comment: @Mihai Yes, too many. Good thinking, i'll add to db. Thanks!

Comment: I dont see any problem, its an optional param `{label?}`,  so any param value will capture

Comment: @sta The issue was that I didn't want all params captured. I had a brain fart and didn't consider whitelisting. Mihai was right and that was the way to go. I've whitelisted all valid params which now sends invalid URLs to 404 rather than as param.